# In Yocto, how do I chose which of multiple sources my patch gets applied to?

Tags: yocto, patch

I have a recipe pulling two repositories `A` going into `${S}` and `B` going into `${Sprime}`. I want a local patch file to apply to the source code in `${Sprime}`. How can I accomplish this? I keep getting a `can't find file to patch` error. Does Yocto only apply patches to the main source repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass `patchdir` as a parameter to your patch in `SRC_URI` the following way:

```
SRC_URI += "file://my.patch;patchdir=path/relative/to/${S}"
#or SRC_URI += "file://my.patch;patchdir=/absolute/path/to/${Sprime}"
```

c.f. https://docs.yoctoproject.org/ref-manual/ref-variables.html#term-SRC_URI